# how to format method with more parameter in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I know CTRL+ SHIFT + F for formatting method but it gives 3-4 parameters in line. I want one parameter in one line

foe eg:

`method(a,b,c,d,e,f)`

I want below result

```
method(a,
       b,
       c,
       d,
       e,
       f)
```

Comment: The best way to format them is to avoid them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an option in Eclipse formatter.

1. Go to `Window > Preferences`
2. Then in the tree on the left, go to `Java > Code Style > Formatter`
3. Go to "Line Wrapping" tab
4. In the tree, choose `Method Declaration > Parameters` or `Function Calls > Arguments`
5. In "Line Wrapping Policy" combo box, choose:

> Wrap all elements, every element on a new line.

Comment: Policy -> Wrap all elements, every element on new line

Comment: @Karna Yeah I was typing ^^

Comment: @wspeirs I would be surprised if there is no similar setting for constructors. I have been using IntelliJ IDEA for a couple years now, so I don't have Eclipse at hand to check unfortunately.

Comment: @Joffrey For constructor calls, use "Object allocation arguments"